# Where can I store my plist online for free and my app can download it?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, hosting, plist

I have an app where it downloads the latest .plist from a URL. Is there a website where I can upload my plist file for free and when users go on my app, it will download the plist with no hassle?

At the moment my app is looking at the plist locally. I want to store my file online so any changes I make, can be uploaded by me and then downloaded when the app is used.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store it online using a free hosted website, like the ones provided by [**en.altervista.org**](http://en.altervista.org/): the site looks like a subdomain (e.g. bigsman.altervista.org), it has got FTP access and other features, all free.
It's the best free solution in my humble opinion. I've already use it in some of my projects, and everything went fine.

Comment: many thanks for your reply, great answer that i shall look into :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like dropbox, or the new google storage, but you would need to check the terms and conditions to see if it is permitted.

If however you want to release your app, the best place would be your support site that you have to create as part of the process

Comment: many thanks for your reply, great answer that i shall look into :)